# How to loop through time in select box PHP

Tags: php, html, select, time, dropdown

I have a select drop down where I want to list times in the format of HH:MM with 1 minute intervals. so the list will start at 00:00 and finish at 23:59

I understand how to create a loop in a select drop down that will output 0-10

`<select><?php for($i=0; $i<10; $i++){echo "<option>" . $i . "</option>";} ?>
 </select>`

and I understand how to output the time as HH:MM

`<option><?php echo date('h:i', $supportrequest->startTime); ?</option>`

But I can't work out how to do a combination of the two as I'm not sure what the parameters of the for loop should be

Comment: Hi, how about you make 2 loops with one for the hours and one for minutes?
0-23 for hour, and 0-59 for minute.

Comment: checkout [DatePeriod](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php)

Comment: If you just want to output numeric values between 0 and 23, and between 0 and 59, why not just use simple for loops?

Comment: You need two loops - one for hours, one for minutes. Store the value in 24h time, format and display as am/pm for user unless they are used to 24hr clock

Answer (score 3):

Using DatePeriod it'd be like that:

```
<?php
$begin = (new DateTime())->setTime(0,0,0);  // create start point
$end = (new DateTime())->setTime(23,59,59); // create end point
$interval = new DateInterval('PT1M'); // set the interval to 1 minute
$daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval ,$end);  // create the DatePeriod

echo "<select>";
foreach($daterange as $date){ // loop through that period
    echo "<option value='".$date->format("H:i") . "'>".$date->format("H:i")."</option>\n";
}
echo "</select>";
```

Using these classes makes it now easy to modify if you f.e. only want to have every 30 minutes, or need a different output format.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really want to have a drop-down with one thousand, four hundred and forty option values (24 * 60 = 1440)? I think it would be better to have two `<select>` elements. You could style them to sit next to each other with a `:` in the middle if you wanted to keep the `'H:m'` look.

```
<select id="hours">
<?php
for ($h = 0; $h < 24; $h++) printf("<option value=\"$h\"" . (!$h ? " selected" : "") . ">%02d</option>", $h);
?>
</select>
<select id="minutes">
<?php
for ($m = 0; $m < 60; $m++) printf("<option value=\"$m\"" . (!$m ? " selected" : "") . ">%02d</option>", $m);
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Converted Mukyuu's comment into an answer:

```
<select>
<?php 
  for($h=0; $h<24; $h++){
    for($i=0; $i<60; $i++){
      $time = date('h:i',strtotime($h.':'.$i));
      echo "<option>".$time."</option>";
    } 
  } 
?>
</select>
```